# neo4j-import with node_auto_indexing

Tags: regex, lucene, neo4j

For a project, I need to import 5 million nodes and 15 millions relations.
I tried to import by batch but it was very slow, so I used the new tool 'Neo4j-import' from Neo4j 2.2. We generate some specifics .csv and use the 'neo4j-import'. It is very fast, the whole database is created in 1mn30.

But the problem is that I need to do a regex query on one property (find a movie with only the beginning of his name). And the average response time is between 2.5 and  4 seconds, which is huge.

I read that with Lucene query it would be much more efficient. But with Neo4-import, nodes are created without the node_auto_indexing.

**Is there a way to use Neo4j-import and have node_auto_indexing in order to use the Lucene query?**

Thanks,

Reptile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`neo4j-import` does not populate auto indexes. For doing you need to trigger a write operation on the the nodes to be auto indexed. Assume you have nodes with a `:Person` label having a `name` property.

Configure node auto index for `name` in `neo4j.properties` and restart Neo4j.

To populate the autoindex run a cypher statement like:

```
MATCH (n:Person) 
WHERE NOT HAS(n.migrated)
SET n.name = n.name, n.migrated=true
RETURN count(n) LIMIT 50000
```

Rerun this statement until the reported count is 0. The rationale for the `LIMIT` is to have transactions of a reasonable size.